# Reversible markov chain

Tags: markov-process

i have a question from a mid session exam. I was marked incorrect and I dont understand why. Question: Given a reversible markov chain P, with measure $\pi$. Show that $P^2$ is reversible.

Since P is reversible $\pi$ is the invariant measure. Since $\pi$ is the invariant measure $\pi P = \pi$. Therefore, $\pi P^2=\pi PP =\pi P$. Which is reversible given from the question.

Comment: This shows that $\pi$ is invariant, not that the chain is [reversible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Reversible_Markov_chain).

Comment: So we cant reduce the terms in this way to show that its reversible too?

Comment: [Kolmogorov's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_criterion) offers one approach to a solution.

Comment: Just apply the definition that $\pi_i p_{ij}=\pi_j p_{ji}$.

Comment: So honestly the reason i didnt use that way is i panicked and forgot where i and j go, so i used what i thought may be a seperate method. I understand it's not the usual way i just dont understand why its wrong...i think you're saying im proving something about the measure rather than the transition matrix. I guess the real question is does invariance imply reversible as reversible implies invariance?